How can i use functions from libc in NASM 64 bit
im making my own programming language and i wanted to call some functions from libc (es strcat and printf) but im unsure on how to call them correctly(i dont which cpu registry to use and if i have to actually use them to pass arguments), by now i got printf to work following a git hub example. (https://gist.github.com/jamichaels/a5e770105615d9e32b18)
This is how i ended up printing stuff:
SECTION .data
     endLine db 0Ah, 0
     integer_printf:     db  '%d',   10,0
     float_printf        db  '%f',   10,0
     string_format       db  '%s',   10,0
     var     db "test",0
SECTION .text
     extern printf
     global main
printInt:
     mov rdi,integer_printf
     xor rax,rax
     call printf
     ret
printFloat:
     mov rdi,float_printf
     call printf
     ret
printStr:
     mov rdi,string_format
     xor rax,rax
     call printf
     ret
exit_program:
     mov rax, 60
     syscall
main:
     mov rsi, var
     call printStr

     MOV rdi, 30
     call exit_program

nasm -f elf64 -o test.o main.asm && gcc -o test test.o -lc -no-pie
thanks in advice for any help


It's unclear what you are asking given you already have working code. Anyway you might want to look at calling convention

@Jester I ment that im not sure for what argument are the registry, like rsi is the first argument for printf but what are the others?

rdi is the first argument. rsi is the second.

@Jester is there a table i can consult?

He already answered that with his "calling conventions" link.

@Streve Ford sorry im a bit tired and i did not notice, have a great day you both

Here is another great resource: https://godbolt.org/z/dhhE4nMWM It lets you enter C code and it shows you the resulting assem output. I've spent hours playing with it. (The link above is a print call I threw together.)

Re: the title question: Can't call C standard library function on 64-bit Linux from assembly (yasm) code is about the actual call instruction if you don't use -no-pie.
